# Forcing HTTPS with subdomains in .htaccess or httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've been unable to get the flow of rewrites in the correct order to force HTTPS *and* redirect to the 'www' domain by default.

What I'm trying to do is force the 'www' domain if none is provided and at the same time, force to HTTPS, while taking into consideration there are two other subdomains that HTTPS is required for as well.

Scenarios:

```
http://[domain.com]/* -> https://www.[domain.com]/*
http://assets.[domain.com]/* -> https://assets.[domain.com]/*
http://payloads.[domain.com]/* -> https://payloads.[domain.com]/*
```

As I understand, this first block check if HTTPS is not on AND if there is no subdomain present, then will redirect to https://www.[domain.com]/

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.|assets\.|payloads\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

While this checks if HTTPS is not on AND a proper subdomain is found, then redirects to https://[subdomain].[domain.com]/

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.|assets\.|payloads\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Although the first condition/rule set successfully redirects to the default www subdomain, it goes into a loop and nothing displays when going to https://www.[domain.com].

Can someone explain what's wrong with my logic? I've looked at other answers here and either they don't help or there are no answers.

If it's more appropriate to force HTTPS in httpd.conf, and leave the redirects to the .htaccess, I can do that as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish with these 2 rules in `httpd.conf` or `vhost.cong` or site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# for assets or payload subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:assets|payloads)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# for rest
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: The assets and payloads redirect seems to work, but the second with www is still in an infinite loop.

Comment: Test is a new browser or completely clear your browser cache.

Comment: Did that (cleared cache in my main browser, cleared everything in my secondary browser). Same issue.

Comment: Then I suspect some other code/plugin causing this behavior.  Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: There was a framework conflict indeed. The PHP-based URL router did not take kindly to these Apache requests, but was able to accomplish this with 3 lines of code in software. However, I tested this on a server not running this software and everything worked just fine - as usual, PHP is the culprit.